# How to convert from mb_convert_encoding($file, 'UTF-8', 'Windows-1251') back?

Tags: php, string, mb-convert-encoding

In php I use

```
mb_convert_encoding($file, 'UTF-8', 'Windows-1251')
```

and I need to convert this back as the output is not human readable. The current output looks like this

```
П„ПѓО№ОЅП„ПѓО№О»О±МЃ_3.jpg
```

When I tried

```
mb_convert_encoding($file, 'ASCII'),
```

it doesn't work.

EDITED:

I use this code to compare strings: There is a problem with diacritic like this: hundezubehör-für-sommer.jpg. Thats why I use the code below.

```
$image_files = scandir($dir);
foreach ($image_files as &$file) {
    $file = mb_convert_encoding($file, 'UTF-8', 'Windows-1251');
}
// ...
var_dump(in_array($file, $image_files));
```

It works fine but the code looks like this П„ПѓО№ОЅП„ПѓО№О»О±МЃ_3.jpg. I want to convert it back to human readable format.

Comment: What is the original filename? I get this when converting back: `τσιντσιλά_3`

Comment: @Michel it it a name of an image: hundezubehör-für-sommer.jpg

Comment: Don't know what you did, but when I put my converted string `τσιντσιλά` trough Google translate, it detects Greek and returns `chinchilla`.

Comment: To convert back you just swap `from_encoding` and `to_encoding`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php

Comment: I just found that I had mistake in another part of code. It works now fine. Thank you